# Expressing elements of a matrix over a polynomial ring as polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory, soft-question

Let $S$ be a ring and let $\theta(x) \in M_n(S[x])$. Then we can write $\theta(x)= \Sigma_0^p \alpha_i x^i$ where $\alpha_i \in M_n(S)$.

This is happening in Lemma 16.4 in Donald Passmans "A Course in Ring Theory." Could somebody help me to see how we can write the matrix like this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.
$$
\pmatrix{x^2+2x+1&1\\ -x^3-x-1&-4x^2+3x}
=\pmatrix{0&0\\ -1&0}x^3
+\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-4}x^2
+\pmatrix{2&0\\ -1&0}x
+\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&0}.
$$